Visual Studio created project with duplicate dir names. How fix this so consolidate directories
I created a Visual Studio Project and it created the dir structure in file explorer like this:
BuildStatusVerification (dir)
    BuildStatusVerification (dir)
    .vs (dir)
    packages (dir)
        BuildStatusVerification.cs (these files are under 2nd BuildStatusVerification dir)
        LoggingHelper.cs
        packages.config
        App.config
        Properties (dir)
        bin (dir)
        obj (dir)
        

How do I consolidate dirs so I don't have two BuildStatusVerification dirs, and all the files are under the top BuildStatusVerification dir? My team is asking for that. I would just leave it but have to do what the team wants.
The closest I can find is add dir tree, but this seems like a completely different thing from what I need. I have a feeling the issue was when I created the project to begin with, but I'd like to avoid recreating the project and moving the files over.

Drag nested folder one level above and fix path in sln file?


Move all files to the top dir BuildStatusVerification
Delete the sub dir BuildStatusVerification
modify paths in the.csproj file


I decided to just recreate the project because it was easier. When I created the project, I made sure to check the box to put solution and project in same folder... 
After that, it was easy to just re-add the classes from my old project to the new project.
